# Angularjs function inside ng-repeat called too many times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-digest

I've got a function in my controller very easy that just stamp a console.log. I need to conditioning a button using a function but inside the ng-repeat the controller repeats everything many times! Is it normal? Is it possible avoid this? Thanks. An example here http://plnkr.co/edit/sME67gQEZQSLI9FOwEAG?p=preview

relative code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.5" data-semver="1.4.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="DigestApp">
    <div ng-controller="UserCtrl as uc">
      <h1>Please open the console to see</h1>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in uc.users" ng-class="uc.userClasses(user)">
          {{user.name}}
          <button ng-if="uc.isUserEnabled(user)"
                  ng-click="uc.disableUser(user)">Disable</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

javascript:

```
angular.module("DigestApp", [])

.controller('UserCtrl', function(User) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.users = User.list();

  vm.isUserEnabled = function(user) {
    console.log('isUserEnabled');
    return user.active;
  };

  vm.userClasses = function(user) {
    console.log('userClasses');
    return []
      .concat(user.active ? ['user-active'] : [])
      .concat(user.loggedIn ? ['user-logged-in'] : [])
      .concat(user.isMe ? ['user-is-me'] : [])
      .join(' ');
  };

  vm.disableUser = function(user) {
    user.active = false;
  };
})

.factory('User', function() {
  return {
    list: function() {
      return [{
        name: "me",
        active: true,
        loggedIn: true,
        isMe: true
      }];
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: this is how `ng-class` directive work.. it evaluates expression on each digest..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. There is no way that angular can tell whether the result of the function will have changed, so it calls it on every digest loop. If you want to avoid that you should calculate the value once and set the result as an attribute on the user object.

```
<li ng-repeat="user in uc.users" ng-class="user.classes">
      {{user.name}}
      <button ng-if="user.active"
              ng-click="uc.disableUser(user)">Disable</button>
</li>
```

and in the controller add some code to precalculate a `user.classes` attribute on each user object (and to update it when you change the state of the model).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Anyway, even if i decide to keep the function in my ng-if, could be create any problem about the performances?

Comment: If the function is quick then there usually won't be a problem unless you have a very large ng-repeat. Basically avoid the function if you can do so easily but if it is hard to do that use a function until performance is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your `li` in the HTML to the below. I got it working here http://plnkr.co/edit/Cx5OZaY0dhmBT4WLYZpX?p=info.

```
<li ng-repeat="user in uc.users" ng-class="{ 'user-active': user.active, 'user-logged-in': user.loggedin, 'user-is-me': user.isme }">
    {{user.name}}
    <button ng-if="user.active" ng-click="uc.disableUser(user)">Disable</button>
</li>
```

By using a function in your `ng-class` and `ng-if` it was evaluating to often. You can just pass the scope variables instead.